# Zend Framework: My composite form doesn't pass atrribs to form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I've created a composite form but the problem is that it doesn't send attribs to my rendered form.

```
    class My_View_Helper_NameElement extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement {
    protected $xhtml = '';
    public function nameElement($name, $value = null, $attribs= null) {
        $helper = new Zend_View_Helper_FormText();
        $helper->setView($this->view);
        $this->xhtml .= $helper->formText($name . '[first_name]', '', array());
        $this->xhtml .= $helper->formText($name . '[last_name]', '', array());
        return $this->xhtml;
        }
    }
```

setAttrib in following code doesn't send the class

```
    $this->xhtml .= $helper->formText($name . '[first_name]', '', array();
    $this->xhtml .= $helper->formText($name . '[last_name]', '', array());
```

Comment: what do you see when you echo $name?

Comment: I get:

`<dt id="name-label">
 <label for="name" class="required">Name:</label>
</dt>

<dd id="name-element">
 <input type="text" name="name[first_name]" id="name-first_name" value="">
 <input type="text" name="name[last_name]" id="name-last_name" value="">
</dd>`

Comment: I'm expecting to be: `<dt id="name-label"> 
<label for="name" class="required">Name:</label> 
</dt> 
<dd id="name-element"> 
<input type="text" name="name[first_name]" id="name-first_name" value="" class="text mini"> 
<input type="text" name="name[last_name]" id="name-last_name" value="" class="text mini"> 
</dd>` it doesn't render class='text mini'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your parent class like the following.

```
$this->xhtml .= $helper->formText($name . '[first_name]', '', array());
```

to

```
$this->xhtml .= $helper->formText($name . '[first_name]', '', array(), $attribs);
```

The above should work. If it doesn't, just use the following code. It will work.

```
$this->xhtml .= $helper->formText($name . '[first_name]', '', array(),
array('class' => 'text mini');
```

Comment: Thanks but none of them work. Why it doesn't work while it's instance of Zend_View_Helper_FormElement.

Comment: @eneepo can you echo $helper->formText($name . '[first_name]', '', array(),
array('class' => 'text mini') in your parent class and check the output?

Comment: Thanks a lot emaillenin, I did what you said but i also removed the first array and it worked: `echo $helper->formText($name . '[first_name]', '', array('class' => 'text mini')` It rendered the class.

Comment: Of course, as soon as I get two extra reputation, I'm a newbie ;)